# create a graph of a region between 2 curves that is rotated about the x-axis

Tags: pgfplots

I can generate a shaded region between 2 curves, using pgfplots.
Say the region between y=4-2x and y=4-x^2.

However, I would like to rotate the said region about the x-axis.

Can this be done efficiently with pgfplots?

Comment: please, show you code in forma of small complete document.

Comment: What do you mean with "rotate about the x-axis"?

Comment: Consider the region bounded by the curves y=4-2x and y=4-x^2. Now take this region and rotate it about the x-axis to generate a volume of revolution.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

`sor.asy` below is based on a modified example `hyperboloid.asy`:

```
// sor.asy
//
// to get sor.pdf, run
//
// asy -f pdf -noprc -render=0 sor.asy
//

size(200);
import solids;
currentprojection=orthographic(camera=(0.02,-18,12),
up=(-1,0.2,0.3),target=(0,0,0),zoom=0.75);

pen pen1 = rgb("fdbb84");
pen pen2 = rgb("2c7fb8");

triple f1(real x){return (x, 4-2x,  0);}
triple f2(real x){return (x, 4-x^2, 0);}
real xmin=0, xmax=2;

revolution s1=revolution(graph(f1, xmin,xmax,20,operator ..),axis=three.X);
revolution s2=revolution(graph(f2, xmin,xmax,20,operator ..),axis=three.X);

draw(surface(s1),pen1,meshpen=nullpen,render(merge=true));
draw(surface(s2),pen2,meshpen=nullpen,render(merge=true));

draw(shift(6,0,0)*rotate(60,three.Y)*surface(s1),pen1,meshpen=nullpen,render(merge=true));
draw(shift(6,0,0)*rotate(60,three.Y)*surface(s2),pen2,meshpen=nullpen,render(merge=true));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I would like to use pgfplots, and in particular the addplot3 command.